# Copy <pkg:part></pkg:part> tags from one <pkg:package></pkg:package> to another using open xml 2.0

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I have retrieved a string of XML which contains the content of a single rich text content control using the property `contentControl.Range.WordOpenXml` in VSTO (C#).

This contains a number of `<pkg:part>` tags enclosed within a `<pkg:package>` tag depending on the content within the content control. If there are images in the content, they are contained inline as a byte array in a different `<pkg:part>` tag.

How do I use this XML to copy the contents of this rich text control to a content control in a different word document.

PS : I am using Open Xml SDK 2.0, C# and Word 2010

Answer (score 2):

Documents and Ranges have a `WordOpenXML` property, as you have discovered. Ranges, however, also have an `InsertXML` method which will take a WordOpenXML string, e.g.:

```
var wordOpenXML = contentControl.Range.WordOpenXml;

document.Range().InsertXML(wordOpenXML);
```

This will result in the contents of the Content Control being inserted into `document`. You can use a more specific Range to determine exactly where the content gets copied to in your document. It will also work within the same document, of course.